# SelectedItem Property is not working

Tags: c#, sql, linq

I am using a linq to sql for populating a combo box. to populate combobox i am using the following code on page load event:

```
ColdStoreDataContext csdc = new ColdStoreDataContext(); 
comboBox1.DisplayMember="Name";
comboBox1.ValueMember="AccountHeadId";
comboBox1.DataSourse=csdc.SupplierPurchase;
```

the above code is working properly but when I use the given code:

```
comboBox.SelectedValue="KAMAL SINGH S/O AJEET SINGH";
```

then it does not properly works means comboBox displayed null value.
Please help me to resolve this problem.

Comment: Can you show us your comboBox values

Comment: MY COMBO BOX VALUES ARE:(DisplayMember:Manoj Kumar S/O Ram Kumar, ValueMember: 1),(DisplayMember:Kamal Singh S/O Ajeet Singh,ValueMember:2)

Comment: That looks a lot like a display string, not a value.

Comment: comboBox.SelectedValue="1"; code is not working.

Comment: Try to use comboBox.SelectedIndex = 0;

Comment: code comboBox.SelectedIndex = 0; is also not working.

Comment: @AvinashSingh Does your comboBox showing anything or not?

Comment: yes it is populated with all records.

Comment: I assume this is a type and you did not copy and paste over but `comboBox.SelectedValue="KAMAL SINGH S/O AJEET SINGH";` should be `comboBox1.SelectedValue="KAMAL SINGH S/O AJEET SINGH";`? Using `comboBox` not `comboBox1`

Answer (score 0):

Your combo box has AccountHeadId as its ValueMember. When you set the combo box's SelectedValue, the box will look in its data source for an item whose AccountHeadId matches the value you just set to SelectedValue.

Try

```
comboBox1.SelectedValue=2;
```

Comment: comboBox.SelectedValue=2; it set a null value to combobox; unfortunately comboBox.SelectedValue=2; code is also not working.

Comment: Oops...based on the code you posted in your original question, it needs to be comboBox1.SelectedValue=2. If that doesn't work, does putting the 2 in quotes work?

Comment: Thanks bro. At last I found the solution. And The Solution is:var item = (from a in csdc.SupplierPurchases select a).ToList();
                    cmbSupplier.SelectedIndex = item.FindIndex(c => c.AccountHeadId == 2);